# Create websites with Android phone?

Tags: development

I have Google searched this many times, but I only get "how to make a mobile version of your website" and such. I want to know if I am able to use my Android phone to write code/script and view the results. If so, how would I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this. You can install different Android apps to edit the code, any HTML editor tool will do -  they can be found in the google play store.

You do not need to make a totally different version of your website, you can use [google's mobile friendly test](https://www.google.co.uk/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/) to check what needs to be changed.

Comment: Then would I just view the site in my browser like on a PC?

Comment: yes @AustinGriner you can use tools like http://quirktools/screenfly to check how different screensizes look